# SAM AWS Serverless Deploy error (CreateChangeSet)

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, sam

I'm trying to get a SAM Serverless application to deploy. I ran SAM validate and also ran it locally no problem.

I'm totally stuck on this error, I'm just not sure what it is asking for. I'm using the simple Codestar example provided by Amazon.

`sam deploy  --template-file output.yaml  --stack-name new-stack-name-xx`

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Parameters: [ProjectId] must have values

Comment: I might have figured it out, I had to use cloudformation  like this:  aws cloudformation deploy  --template-file output.yaml  --stack-name mystacknotyours  --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --parameter-overrides ProjectId=wow99712

Answer (score 0):

Comment the key (`ProjectId`) inside the parameters section.

```
Parameters:
    ProjectId:
    *****
```